# Is finite abelian group isomorphism in Log Space?

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, group-theory

**Definition :**  An abelian group is a group in which the result of applying the group operation to two group elements does not depend on the order in which they are written

**Input :** Two finite abelian groups $|G| =n$ and $|H|=n$ by their table representation

**Find :** Is $G \cong H$?

There is an $O(n)$ running time algorithm for this problem, due to Kavitha [1].

**Question :** Is this problem known to be in Log Space?

I tried to google but did not get anything related to log space.

---

[1] T. Kavitha, *Linear time algorithms for Abelian group isomorphism and related problems*. *Journal of Computer and System Sciences* 73(6):986–996. ([Science Direct](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022000007000293))

Answer (score 2):

The finite abelian group-isomorphism when groups are given in the form of multiplication tables known to be in $L$ and in $TC^0 (FOLL)$. For more detail you can see the thesis of the Dr. Fabian.

PhD  [Thesis](https://oparu.uni-ulm.de/xmlui/bitstream/handle/123456789/3923/vts_7264_10267.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y) of Dr. Fabian ( see page number 180 and 185 )